# Static Inheritance and SUPER keyword

Tags: apex, design-patterns, inheritance

Question about how static member/method inheritance works in apex:

For reference, this question is related, but doesn't address my question or take into account my findings: [reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294691/does-salesforce-apex-support-inheritance-of-static-methods)

I have a factory base class, with only static members and methods that are not allowed to be declared virtual:

```
public virtual class Fact_BaseFactory 
{
    /******** MEMBERS REGION ********/

    private static Map<String, Schema.DisplayType> fieldNameToTypeMap = new Map<String, Schema.DisplayType>();

    private static Map<String, ID> recordTypes = new Map<String, ID>();

    /******** PRIVATE HELPER REGION ********/

    //attaches newly inserted, factory-produced lookup record
    private static void populateFieldNameToTypeMap(String objectName)
    {
         List<String> objNames = new List<String>();
         objNames.add(objectName);
         Schema.DescribeSobjectResult objDescribe = Schema.describeSObjects(objNames)[0];
         for (Schema.SObjectField objectFields : objDescribe.fields.getMap().values())
         {
             Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = objectFields.getDescribe();
             fieldNameToTypeMap.put(fieldDescribe.getName(), fieldDescribe.getType());
         }
     }
}
```

Which I use to extend an SObject factory from:

```
global class Fact_Account extends Fact_BaseFactory
{
    public class AccountFactoryException extends Exception { }

    //define default constants
    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = 'FactoryAccount';
    public static final String DEFAULT_ENTITY_Id = 'Foo_North_America';


    /******** STATIC INITIALIZATION REGION ********/

    static 
    {
        //base class method
        super.populateFieldNameToTypeMap('Account');        

        //base class member
        recordTypes = UtilityMethods_Data.mapOfAccountRecordTypes();
    }

    //rest of class
}
```

My question is about the SUPER keyword seen here in the static initialization block of the subclass.  The code as shown compiles correctly, but if I remove the super keyword, I get a 'Variable does not exist: recordTypes' error because the static members/methods are not inherited from the base class.

However, because I use the super keyword to reference a method from the base-class, somehow this allows me to directly reference all of the static members/methods of the base class in the subclass (without super keyword), as long as I use the super keyword to call a base-class method (HAS to be method) before the super-less base-class reference (member OR method).

Without the super keyword, the compiler seems to search for base-class members first to error on, and if there are no base-class members it errors on base-class method references.  I think that's due to compilation-step order and not because of different treatment of static member vs static method on the base class.

1. Is this a known/acceptable use of SUPER to enable inheritance from one wholly static class to another wholly static class?
2. Is this a poor design because it's not readable/maintainable anyway, with two options I can see to replace:

a)  Change Fact_BaseFactory into a utility class (Fact_FactoryHelper) with all static methods, and move static members from base into ex-subclasses (violates DRY).

b)  Composition instead of inheritance.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing it's a bug along the lines of compiling `public class MyClass<T> { }`, but then not allowing you to re-compile the code.

Comment: TIL Salesforce Apex supports instance and static initializers. Did not know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your code doesn't compile now. That explains a lot.

Secondly, in my opinion messing with polymorphism in static classes (wholly static as you said) is not a good design at all. I don't see any good reason (although there might be some) driven by design needs to do try to access static method with `super`. But question is still interesting, so let's move on.

Third thing is, you use `super` keyword to reference private member. It shouldn't be possible at all. Private is private. If it compiled somehow, that was certainly a bug.

Answering to point 1: 
As I said, I can't see any reason to inherit from static class. Actually It's not even an inheritance, you can access **public** members of any other static class anyway like listed below. Moreover, it's not permitted now - when I tried to compile your code (and many of it's variations :) I get the `Variable does not exist: this` error from line -1 (valuable clue!). Not surprisingly, the code like this works fine, and it doesn't grant any access to other private members:

```
public virtual class Fact_BaseFactory 
{
    public static void populateFieldNameToTypeMap(String objectName) { ... }
}



public class Fact_Account extends Fact_BaseFactory
{
    static 
    {
        Fact_BaseFactory.populateFieldNameToTypeMap('Account');
    }
}
```

According to second question:

**A)**
This idea seems to be the way to go, I would just create some public method In the helper class and reuse the code within your factories. Not sure what you mean with violating DRY here.

**B)**
Composition instead of inheritance is good design in general based on my experience and it's also recommended by Head First "Design Patterns" book. I would stick to the A anyway, but it's a good question to ask on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for the detailed analysis.  Really appreciate your input.  SfdcFox turned me on to the false-positive compilations that can happen, especially with the Tooling API, and I was able to determine that my code was never truly compiling anyway.  I ended up adopting composition to solve this problem.  You've added some great detail to my understanding of how to architect in the future.  Thanks.  I open-sourced the code, so you can see the implementation here:  https://github.com/DavidWaughSFDC/SFDC-Flexible-Factory-Methods/blob/master/src/classes/Fact_BaseComponent.cls

Comment: I have a use case where I want to make my static service classes inherit from a common base where I define props that are commonly used so I don't have multiple initializations going on.  But it doesn't seem you can access static props from the child classes so after reading your answer I gave up.